# Is that possible to remove a null character Char(0) from NetworkStream w/o encoding it?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, xml-deserialization, networkstream

I have a deserializer function which gets the input as NetworkStream type and deserialized it then returns as my pre defined object type (PreDefinedObj)

```
Private Function Deserializer(ByVal respondedNS As NetworkStream) As PreDefinedObj

        Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(PreDefinedObj))

        Dim deserializedObj As PreDefinedObj

        deserializedObj  = CType(serializer.Deserialize(respondedNS ), PreDefinedObj)

        Return deserializedObj  
End Function
```

What I would like to do is, I would like to remove null characters from my ns variable (networkStream) before I send it to be deserialized. 
Look below please:

```
Dim ns As NetworkStream

Dim myPreDefinedObj As PreDefinedObj

ns = getSomething(stringXML)'This function returns NetworkStream type response' 
'The response value (in NetworkStream type) come from  the server that I do not have an access to server to fix the return value to not include the null characters.'

myPreDefinedObj = Deserializer(ns)

Return myPreDefinedObj
```

Hope the problem is clear.

I'm looking for the way to do that w/o encoding it to string. I can encode it by using `[Byte]()` but then I'm not sure after removing null characters from the string, how I will roll it back to NetworkStream type again.

Is that possible to remove null characters from a variable in type of NetworkStream? If so, then how to do that?

NOTE: Also , I'm using vb.net but C# suggestions would be apprecitated as well.

Thanks

**EDIT:** I would like to give more information about the `getSomething()` function

```
Public Shared Function getSomething(ByVal stringXML As String) As NetworkStream

Try
    Dim tcpClient As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient() 
    Dim requestedURL As String = "xxx.xxx.x.x" 
    Dim portNumber As String = "xxxx"

    tcpClient.Connect(requestedURL, portNumber )

    Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = tcpClient.GetStream()

    If networkStream.CanWrite And networkStream.CanRead Then

        Dim sendBytes As [Byte]() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringXML)

        networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
        'I would like to know If I can remove null characters before return networkStream'        
        Return networkStream
     Else
         tcpClient.Close() 
     End If
Catch e As Exception
     'do something'    
Throw e
End Try

   Throw New Exception("No value returned")

End Function
```

Comment: Why do you have the bad data to start with? I would try to track down and fix the cause rather than the symptoms.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I %100 agree with you, but I wish I had an access to do that. The data come from the Server that I don't have an access to fix the return value.  Thanks for suggesstion tho.

Comment: But how has it got in there? I would be nervous that there's a lot more wrong with it than just extra "0-bytes". I think it's worth investigating whether you're losing legitimate data, for example.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Unfortunately I have no idea why "0-bytes " are returned in response value, but only thing I'm sure is I have to deal with this as soon as possible :(

Comment: I wonder if this is a case of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What error/s do you get? Does the stream length match the expected length?

Comment: @groverboy: I get TimeOut error. But when I set the timeout to enough time, since response has null characters , It takes too long to deserialize it. That's why I was trying to get rid off those null characters in response NetworkStream value before deserialize them.

Comment: VB and C# handle null characters in strings differently. What works in VB will require a different process in C#.

Comment: @AdamZuckerman: the reason I said if any suggestion would made as C# based, at least I would have something to search to apply it to vb.

Comment: A stream that contains null characters doesn't seem likely to cause the deserializer to take "too long". Rather, if the stream contains invalid characters then the deserializer will report an error. Where are the null characters, exactly?

Comment: Also, not converting the byte array from the Read can lead to issues if your stream can have multiple types of character encoding (ASCII, UTF-8, or UTF-16).

Comment: @groverboy: Thx for trying to help. Null character are at the end of the response. the way how I saw it that I encode it to string and log to text file. It seems Im reading more than server sent, therefore it adds null characters to the end. But do you have any idea how I can only read the real values (except null characters at the end) ?

Comment: There should be no need to encode (decode, actually) the NetworkStream to string before you write to a file. Then writing to file requires encoding again to a new byte stream. What do you get when you simply write the NetworkStream bytes directly to a file? And, does the deserializer behave the same if you deserialize this file?

Comment: @groverboy:  When I try to write the response to file, I can see the result that I would like to get, but there are also so many null characters at the end of the response. I also edited my question to give more information about what I do in getSomething() function. I appreciate for help. Actually I'm really wondering about , Is that possible to remove null characters from a variable in type of NetworkStream?

Comment: Thanks you for adding the `getSomething` code. I'm not sure that it's valid to read (deserializer) from a NetworkStream immediately after writing to it. Assuming that it is valid, why does `getSomething` encode the XML string to ASCII? Is ASCII the value of the XML _encoding_ attribute? This seems very unusual. If not, what happens if you change the function to use the same encoding?